# How to convert string to dictionary key with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There are some posts about this subject already, but this use case is a bit different in my point of view. I'd like to change my dictionary item key depending on the function call, so for the code below, we need to focus on `field` parameter only.

As you can see `field` parameter contains `'font_size'` string, I'd like to be able to alter `t.fields.`**`variable`** to `t.fields.`**`font_size`** depending on the `field` variable's name.

**Javascript :**

```
function obj_stringify(type, field, name, value) {

  data.forEach(function(d, index){
    var mindex = index;
    d.forEach(function(t) {
      if (t.type == type) {
         if (t.infos == name) {
            t.fields.field = value; /* would become : t.fields.font_size = value; */
         }
      }
    });
  });

  $('#json_dt_r').val(JSON.stringify(data[0], undefined, 4));
  $('#json_dt_v').val(JSON.stringify(data[1], undefined, 4));
}
```

---

**Call :**

```
obj_stringify('text', 'font_size', element_name, fontsize);
```

I wasn't sure if it was possible to alter key with function arguments, is there a way?

Comment: `t.fields[field] = value;` See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I couldn't formulate the question properly so I didn't find this post